# couldn't call the user defined method in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-location, cllocation

I am using core location framework. I am checking Authorization status (`kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied/kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted`) in user-defined method.
The noticeable point is this method is being called in case of the normal flow of execution (there is no problem).

But in the case of when the user quit/terminated the app and again relaunch it (by tapping on app icon). In this case, before and after methods will be called and only this(`Authorization()`) method won't call.
Why did this abrupt behaviour happen? 
Can anybody tell me execution flow in Objective C?

In .h file -

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) LocationTracker * locationTracker;
```

In .m file -

```
    [self userTrialMethodBefore];
      [self.locationTracker startLocationTracking];
      [self userTrialMethodAfter];

- (void)userTrialMethodBefore
        { 
           NSLog(@"This method gets called before ");

         }


        - (void)startLocationTracking
        { 
            NSString *responeParam = @"";
            if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] == NO)
            {
                responeParam = @"Disabled location";
            }
            else
            {

                CLAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus= [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];


                if(authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied || authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted)
                {
                    responeParam = @"Unauthorize location";

                }
                else
                {
                    responeParam = @"Authorize location";


                    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [LocationTracker sharedLocationManager];
                    locationManager.delegate = self;
                    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
                    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
                    if (SystemVersion > 9.2)
                    {

                        [locationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];
                        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false;
                    }

                    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
                }
            }
        }

- (void)userTrialMethodAfter
        { 
           NSLog(@"This method gets called after ");

         }
```

**[Note: I am using Xcode 9.2, iOS 11.2.2 device, objective c language]**

Comment: Show us your code, how you check for authorization, what you expect to be called and ecc...

Comment: @Shebuka Hey Thanks for the reply. The code has just added. have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere when you allocate the `CLLocationManager` you need also to call the `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` like this:

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

and why you are not using `self.locationTracker` to `startUpdatingLocation` but instead retrieve a `sharedLocationManager`?